# Photon Bolt | Compile Assembly gives errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am new to Photon Bolt. I am getting some errors while following the manual.

I have a Bolt Entity attached to multiple prefabs.
These errors occur every time I run the Compile Assembly.

The details of the error are as follows.

---

```
  D:\UnityProjects\ProjectName\Temp\bolt\prefabs.cs(91,40): error CS0102: The type `BoltPrefabs' already contains a definition for `Obj1'
   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
   Bolt.Editor.Compiler.BoltUserAssemblyCompiler:ErrorDataReceived(Object, DataReceivedEventArgs)
   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()
```

---

```
D:\UnityProjects\ProjectName\Temp\bolt\prefabs.cs(23,40): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Bolt.Editor.Compiler.BoltUserAssemblyCompiler:ErrorDataReceived(Object, DataReceivedEventArgs)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()
```

---

I don't want to make a lot of changes because the cause of the error is not in the Asset file.
If anyone knows the cause and solution of this error please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a prefab with the same name in another folder.
Naturally it causes interference.